# Positioning UILabels in scroll view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I use many UILabels in my view in a scroll view. I have problems positioning them.

I add the labels programitically because the text changes dynamically in the detail view.

Comment: Michael, what kind of problems are you trying to overcome?  Give a brief on the app or at least some detail on what you want to have them be able to do.  Cheers!

Comment: @Kenny, I think you meant to direct that question to the OP, which I am not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if the UILabels need to be multiline you need to calculate the size of the string being placed in the UILabels first (using NSString's `-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`). Then you keep a reference to the frame of the label so that you can put the next UILabel below or the right or wherever you are scrolling to. Example:

```
UILabel *label = <first UILabel>;
CGRect frame = label.frame;
label = <second UILabel>
frame.origin.y += frame.size.height;
label.frame = frame;
```